# Bootstrap ExtendedGridview with relationalcolumn

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

Let me explain with example so that it will be clear.

StudentDept - Table

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════╦
║ ID ║ Student ║  DEPT ║ 
╠════╬═════════╬═══════╬
║  1 ║ AA      ║ EEE   ║   
║  2 ║ BB      ║ CSE   ║     
║  3 ║ CC      ║ CSE   ║     
║  4 ║ DD      ║ ECE   ║    
║  5 ║ EE      ║ EEE   ║      
╚════╩═════════╩═══════╩
```

In the Bootstrap Extended Grid view i need to show only the DEPT and on click of the DEPT i need to show all the Student related to that dept.

So for the listing of Distinct DEPT i used the dataprovider with criteria like

```
     $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('StudentDept', array(
                        'criteria'=>array('select'=>'DISTINCT Dept' )
                     ));
```

In this since i use DISTINCT of DEPT, i can't get row id or primary keyid, which is required to use tbrelationcolumn.

How to fix this, i want to list all the student comparing the DEPT name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need not to show students, only the dept, and then make it so when you click dept another table will show up with students, why are you doing it this way?